# how to get list of databases from MS Access?

Tags: database, ms-access

I want to get list of databases in MS Access.

How to get list of databases from Ms-access? I want to get databases name from ms access, so what is the query?

I tried "show databases" query not working?

Comment: `C:\>dir c:\*.accdb /s` or use *.mdb if prior to version 2003. Other file types here http://www.access-programmers.com/file-extensions.aspx

Answer (score 1):

MS Access doesn't have a server like SQL server. It is simply a File. So there is no such thing as list of databases. You may search a directory for MS Access Files to list **Access Files** . You may see [this](http://oakdome.com/programming/SQL_FileListing.php) and [this](http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/199073-file-list-creator) to list directories. but I haven't tested it

Comment: k..but how could i write query for it??

Comment: ya ..thanks it working in cmd i am using this code in java.so i want query syntax to use in rs.executeQuery("query"); or how could i use it in java?

Comment: I am not java programmer you may google it. If it answers your current question please accept it